# Can this be reworked with a hot air gun?

Tags: soldering, microchip, heat, rework

I posted before about the Microchip RN4020 (Bluetooth Low Energy) PicTail failing. I have some spare RN4020 modules and access to a heat gun. If I can take this RN4020 off and put a new one on, how would you suggest I do it? Or is it too large or difficult because of the package?

[image]

Comment: The pads at the bottom are going to be the hard ones.

Comment: Those are the same pads - they are plated through holes cut in half.  What will probably happen if not very careful is the shield can and internal components will come off first - but not a big deal if you've already decided the existing module is bad.  Try to clean up and put the new one on with an iron.

Comment: Just checked the datasheet. They are all castellations and not in fact plain pads as they appear in the photo.

Comment: Also lots of flux will help and sometimes you can heat up stubborn pads with a soldering iron while under the heat gun.  You can also put a bunch of solder on there first, just bridge everything.  That'll help transfer and retain some heat.

Comment: Heat guns aren't ideal for soldering -- they tend to spew heat all over the board indiscriminantly, causing unwanted secondary damage, delamination, etc. A Hot Air Rework Station is a better instrument because its nozzle focuses the hot air just on the pins.. But for a small board like this, with not much else on the board, the plain heat gun might work well enough. If the switch and the SOT-223 fall off during rework, those should be easy to remount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to rework it. I got access to a hot air gun. It took a lot of work to get the part off. I had to re-solder the pins of the new one with a soldering iron. There wasn't enough solder after getting the part off, plus the connections weren't good enough with the hot air gun.